# if $f(x)$ is a fifth root polynomial,then number of roots of $f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2 = 0$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is a fifth order polynomial in $x$ and every root of $f(x) = 0$ is real and distinct.

then the number of roots of $f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2 = 0$

Attempt: if $f(x)$ is a fifth root polynomial then $f(x) = 0$ has either $1$ or $3$ or $5$ real roots

further $\displaystyle f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2 = 0 = \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\bigg)=0$

could some help me how to go further, thanks

Comment: Why are you suggesting it has either 1 or 3 or 5 roots? We are already told "every root of f(x) is real and distinct"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's denote the $5$ distinct real roots of $f(x)$ as $a_i , i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$
Now note that

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^5\frac{1}{x-a_i}$$
$$\left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)' = - \sum_{i=1}^5\frac{1}{(x-a_i)^2}$$ 
For $x \ne a_i$, we can write
$$f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2 =(f(x))^2\left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)' = -(f(x))^2 \sum_{i=1}^5\frac{1}{(x-a_i)^2} $$
So, we see the above expression is negative for real $x \ne a_i$. So, the only possible candidates for real roots of $f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2$ are the $a_i$'s.

Now, $f''(a_i)f(a_i)-(f'(a_i))^2 = 0 \Rightarrow f'(a_i)= 0$. But then $f(a_i) = f'(a_i) = 0$ meaning $a_i$ is a repeated root contradicting that $f$ has all real distinct roots. Thus the $a_i$'s can't be roots of $f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2$ either. That is, $f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2$ has no real roots.

I assumed you meant $f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2$ has no real roots because it always has complex roots.