# $[f'(x)]^2-f(x)f''(x)$ has no real roots, if $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i)$, $x_i$ be distinct real numbers

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$[f'(x)]^2-f(x)f''(x)$ has no real roots, if $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i)$, $x_i$ be distinct real numbers

How to prove it? Clearly, we should consider $f'(x)/f(x)$. But how to do next?

Comment: $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x-x_i}$ does not have critical points when $x_i$'s are different, so the function $\frac{f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2}{\{f(x)\}^2}=0$ does not have any real roots.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2208022/42969. That is about a 5th degree polynomial, but the method works for arbitrary polynomials with distinct real zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go ahead
$$\log f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log (x-x_k)$$
Differentiate w.r. t.$x$
$$\frac{f'}{f}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(x-x_k)}$$
Again differentiate w.r.t. $x$
$$\frac{ff'-f'^2}{f^2}=-\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(x-x_k)^2}$$
$$\implies f(x(f'(x)-f'(x)^2=-[(x-x_2)^2(x-x_3)^2....(x-x_n)^2+(x-x_1)^2(x-x_3)^2 (x-x_4)^2...(x-x_n)^2+......]<0$$
RHS being sum of perfect squares which cannot be zero for any one value of $x$.